# Fallback to a static origin when receiving HTTP 404 in nginx-ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a web application running on Kubernetes, and an `nginx-ingress` which serves as the Ingress for the deployment.

I'd like to enable the following behavior for nginx: **when any request receives a HTTP 404 response from the origin, proxy the request to a second, static source.**

I know how to enable that behavior on a standard nginx deployment, but how can it be done using `nginx-ingress` with minimal effort (i.e. providing a full custom configuration file is something I prefer to avoid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [nginx-ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) you can use [default backend](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#default-backend) annotation. In documentation you can read:

> This annotation is of the form
>   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: < svc name > to specify a
>   custom default backend. This < svc name > is a reference to a service
>   inside of the same namespace in which you are applying this
>   annotation. This annotation overrides the global default backend.
>
> This service will be handle the response when the service in the
>   Ingress rule does not have active endpoints. It will also handle the
>   error responses if both this annotation and the custom-http-errors
>   annotation is set.

So you can just create your default service pointing to some backend (pod) serving your static website

So your ingress now should look like this:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: default-backend
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: myservice
          servicePort: 80
```

and your default service like this:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: default-backend
spec:
  selector:
      app: myapp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

For accessing external static resources I tried using service of type `ExternalService` but it seems to crash my `nginx-ingress-controller` pod so I wouldn't recommend using it. If you want to access external resources (outside of cluster) create pod that will proxy requests to this external service and point your ingress's default-backend to its service.

Let me know if this helped